# How to design vertical tab view in jsp and handle then in controller

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I have a requirement as follows.

In the left side of the page there are some links when somebody clicks the links on the left side a proper view is available on the right side.How to do this efficiently in spring MVC.

For example we can see FACEBOOK settings .
  https://www.facebook.com/settings
 but than when you click on general 
 https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=account
or security link on the side 
 https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security

ans so forth. How to handle this ? tab in controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tiles [Here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-tiles-plugin-tutorial-example-eclipse/) is a nice example.